# Scapy - Referencing multiple fields from a FieldLenField

Tags: python, field, layer, scapy

I have reached the next situation, I need to define a new protocol layer in Scapy and one of the fields has a variable size (1,2,3 or 4 bytes) that depends on the size of other specific layer. This is the situation:

```
class newLayer(Packet):
      name = "newLayer fixed header"
      fields_desc = [
          ByteField("msgtype",0),
              # Some other fields ...
          FieldLenField("length", XXX), # length of newLayer_specific layer
                        # This field can be 1,2,3 or 4 bytes long depending
                        # on the length of the variable header
        ]

class newLayer_specific(Packet):
      name = "variable header"
      fields_desc = [
              FieldLenField("length2","field1"), # This field is always 2 bytes long
              StrLenField("field1","",length_from = lambda pkt:pkt.length2),
              StrLenField("field2","", length_from = lambda pkt:pkt.underlayer.length - pkt.length - 2)
              # 2 is because the length of the length2 field 

bind_layers(newLayer, newLayer_specific, msgtype=1)
```

I don´t know how I can refer to the size of the `newLayer_specific` layer from the field `length` of the layer `newLayer`
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use an unconditional layer binding between `newLayer` and `newLayerSpecific`, maybe we can use one single layer. In that case, I would use the `adjust` parameter to handle length here:

```
class NewLayer(Packet):
    name = "NewLayer"
    fields_desc = [
        FieldLenField("length", None, length_of="field2",
                      adjust=lambda pkt, val: val + 2 + len(pkt.field1)),
        FieldLenField("length_field1", None, length_of="field1"),
        StrLenField("field1", "", length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.length_field1),
        StrLenField("field2", "",
                    length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.length - pkt.length_field1 - 2),
    ]
```

Now, we can test the result by running:

```
NewLayer(field1="test", field2="tototiti")
str(_)
NewLayer(_)
```

If your first length field has a variable size, you can just replace `FieldLenField` with a `VariableFieldLenField` that you would have to implement (an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43717630/3223422)).

If, for some reason, you cannot or do not want to use only one layer, here is what I suggest: you can "cheat" with the `length_of` parameter, and use the `adjust` parameter to do the job:

```
class NewLayer(Packet):
    name = "NewLayer"
    fields_desc = [
        FieldLenField("length", None, length_of="length",
                      adjust=lambda pkt, x: len(pkt.payload)),
    ]

class NewLayerSpecific(Packet):
    name = "NewLayer Specific"
    fields_desc = [
        FieldLenField("length_field1", None, length_of="field1"),
        StrLenField("field1", "", length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.length_field1),
        StrLenField("field2", "",
                    length_from=lambda pkt: (pkt.underlayer.length
                                             - pkt.length_field1 - 2),
        ),
    ]

bind_layers(NewLayer, NewLayerSpecific)
```

Again, we can test:

```
NewLayer()/NewLayerSpecific(field1="test", field2="tototiti")
str(_)
NewLayer(_)
```

Comment: Lots of thanks Pierre both solutions work correctly, awesome knowledge!